# How to retrieve current filtered elements inner filterAcceptsRow method in QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

In order to filter a TreeView with two levels (see image below), I used the class QSortFilterProxyModel which has a QStandardItemModel as source model.

to ignore the filtering of the root nodes, I overloaded the `filterAcceptsRow()` method as follows.

this is my main project working with copy/paste a code below model class, i replaced data import from database with a dummy data dictionary

```
import  sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QSortFilterProxyModel


services =[{'id':1,'chanel_name':'France 24','satId':0},
           {'id':2,'chanel_name':'Eurosport 02','satId':0},
           {'id':3,'chanel_name':'CANAL +','satId':0},
           {'id':4,'chanel_name':'Eurosport 02','satId':0},
           {'id':5,'chanel_name':'TV 5','satId':0},
           {'id':6,'chanel_name':'BBC World','satId':0},
           {'id':7,'chanel_name':'M6','satId':0},
           {'id':15,'chanel_name':'TEVA','satId':0},
           {'id':8,'chanel_name':'PLANETTE','satId':1},
           {'id':9,'chanel_name':'France 2','satId':1},
           {'id':10,'chanel_name':'France 3','satId':1},
           {'id':11,'chanel_name':'MBC 1','satId':1},
           {'id':12,'chanel_name':'NIL TV','satId':1},
           {'id':13,'chanel_name':'M2','satId':1},
           {'id':14,'chanel_name':'CANAL 02','satId':1},
           {'id':15,'chanel_name':'CHANEL 1','satId':2},
           {'id':8,'chanel_name':'CINE+ FAMILY','satId':2},
           {'id':9,'chanel_name':'OCS CITY','satId':2},
           {'id':10,'chanel_name':'OCS CHOCS','satId':2},
           {'id':11,'chanel_name':'ACTION','satId':2},
           {'id':12,'chanel_name':'NATIONAL GEO','satId':2},
           {'id':13,'chanel_name':'TVEA','satId':2},
           {'id':14,'chanel_name':'CANAL 02','satId':2},

]

class ProxyServiceBySatModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()


    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row,0,source_parent)
        if  not source_parent.isValid():
             return  True
        else:
            return QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow(self,source_row, source_parent)



class ServicesBySat(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServicesBySat,self).__init__()
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Sat name'])
        self.satellite = ['ASTRA 19° E','HotBird 13°','NILSAT 7° W']

    def importData(self, root=None):
        sats= {}
        root = self.invisibleRootItem()
        for service in services:

            sat = service['satId']

            if sat not in sats:
                parent = root
                parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(self.satellite[sat]))
                sats[sat] = parent.child(parent.rowCount() - 1)
            else:
                parent = sats[sat]
                parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(service['chanel_name']))


class MainWindowISE(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Tree search')
        self.setGeometry(100,100,300,300)
        self.setupUi()
        self.model = ServicesBySat()
        self.model.importData()
        self.proxyModel = ProxyServiceBySatModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.treeView_services.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.lineEdit_Search.textEdited.connect(self.on_lineEditSearch_textEdited)




    def setupUi(self):
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Search : ", self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit_Search = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_Search)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.treeView_services = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView_services, 1, 0, 1, 1)



    def on_lineEditSearch_textEdited(self):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegularExpression(self.lineEdit_Search.text())


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =MainWindowISE()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the filtering works well, but now to improve the behavior of my filter, i want to hide the root nodes that have not a childrens in filtered items by adding a condition like this considering that **self** is my proxy model.

For example,as shown in the representation below, i don't want the NILESAT element  be displayed since it has no children who match the filter pattern

[image]

I modified my method as follows, to achieve the expected result but without success.

class ProxyServiceBySatModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def **init**(self,):
        super().**init**()

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row,0,source_parent)
    if  not source_parent.isValid() and self.hasChildren(index) :
         return  True
    else:
        return QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow(self,source_row, source_parent)
```

or i can use this condition but a get the same result.

```
if  not source_parent.isValid() and self.rowCount(index) > 0 :
```

but i get an exeption

> QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapToSource

how is it possible to get the current row Count or hasChildren value inner filterAcceptsRow method, or another way  to achieve the expected result.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: This looks very similar to [this `c++` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125064/keep-structure-using-qsortfilteritemproxy/61127221#61127221).

Comment: @eyllanesc  sorry i added some code to make it clearer, at least the essentials of the filtering process

Comment: @G.M. it is not exactly the same case, for my part I would like to avoid displaying parent nodes if they have no children who meet the filter criteria.
otherwise in the main the filter works well as we can see on the image, I do not lose the structure of my tree.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have added a working code, with dummy data